# How to automatically add a module rule to react-scripts' webpack.config.js when using "npm install"

Tags: node-modules, create-react-app, react-scripts, webpack.config.js

I've built my application with `create-react-app`, and to make it work I have to add

```
 {
          test: /node_modules.+js$/,
          loader: require.resolve("ify-loader"),
 },
```

to the `module.rules` array of `react-scripts`' `webpack.config.js` file.

What I should I do to make it add automatically when creating the `node_modules` folder with the command `npm install`?